# Can I make a ext4 bootable usb?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, ext4

If yes,how can I do ? It will be really helpful if someone answers.

I use rufus for creating a bootable usb. i am stuck in the grub rescue mode with no way other than installing again but since I cannot enter into Bios, I am planning to boot from the grub rescue windows using the ls function

Grub rescue does not detect the normal Windows Partition so I am planning to make a ext4 bootable kali linux usb so that I can reinstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, your question is unclear.
I suppose this:

1. You want to preserve the main part of your USB as FAT32 storage 14GB
2. You want LiveUSB part in Ext4 2GB

Then the layout of your USB follow:

`sdb1` 14GB `FAT32` storage and EFI folder
`sdb2`  2GB `Ext4` LiveUSB

1. You have to create the `FAT32` part fist to be seen under Windows, as without many tweak, Windows only mount the 1st partition of your USB
2. This `FAT32` partition also hold EFI folder to boot your LiveUSB part
3. If you want the LiveUSB partition `sdb2` on `Ext4`. By default, the built-in `bootx64.efi` of the LiveUSB will not boot an `Ext4` partition.
   So I have made a tweaked `bootx64.efi`. You just copy the file to `sdb1/EFI/boot/`. And it will boot your `Ext4` LiveUSB part.

All of my detail here https://github.com/sonvirgo/Ext4-LiveUSB

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install a Linux OS on a USB to boot from, you should just be able to do it the normal way (i.e., the use of an ext filesystem should not require doing things in a different way than you would for a different filesystem). Also, this question has been answered before:  [Ext2 or Ext4 for bootable USB Flash-drive with Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/238123/ext2-or-ext4-for-bootable-usb-flash-drive-with-linux)

If I understand correctly, you want to make a bootable USB with Kali on it. And from within there, you want to clean install on you main drives.  If you need some specific instructions, this tutorial should help: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-kali-live-usb-drive-with-persistence-optional-0162253/ .  It shows how to make a bootable Kali USB, and from within there you can install Kali on a partition in ext4 format.  The tutorial is supplementary information.  It is detailed and quite long, with extensive pictures, so it would not be practical to replicate it here.

Comment: How is *the normal way* a useful answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your question, so you want to make a bootable usb with Kali on, am I correct? And from within there you want to clean install on you main drives right? If so, this tutorial should help: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-kali-live-usb-drive-with-persistence-optional-0162253/ This tutorial makes a bootable Kali usb, and from within there you can install Kali on a partition in ext4 format.

Comment: Comments aren't permanent, and what's in them can't be searched when other readers are looking for solutions.  It's better to incorporate all essential information into your answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, done ^^